# script running in java swing needs to wait for threads to finish

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I have a java swing application that is running scripts using javax.script. The
scripts access the swing widgets and simulate user actions, like `JButton.doClick()`.
Some of the widget actions cause one or more `Threads (SwingWorker)` to start, and
I need the script to wait until all the `Threads` have completed. But the scripts run
in the Event Dispatch Thread, so if I do, for example, a `CountDownLatch` with an
`await()` inside a `FutureTask`, then `submit()` and `get()`, the `get()` will stop the
EDT, and the GUI hangs. No way to have the script wait without stopping the EDT.
Any workarounds for this problem?

Thanks

Comment: You're going to have to post some code.

Comment: Search for `javax.swing.SwingWorker`.

Answer (score 3):

I faced a similar problem to this in one of my recent projects. The way I got around it was to get the EDT to create (and run) a new `anonymous SwingWorker`, that then called (and waited for) my threads:

```
public void methodCalledByEDT() {
    new SwingWorker<Void, Void>() {
        public Void doInBackground() {
            // Execute threads and wait for them here
            // using the method you described above
            return Void;
        }

        public Void done() {
            // Code to execute when threads have finished goes here
            return Void;
        }
    }.execute()
}
```

This makes sure that the EDT is free to carry on with it's business - it's the anonymous SwingWorker that gets blocked waiting for the threads to finish.

Answer (score 0):

Construct your threads with a `java.lang.ThreadGroup` as their ThreadGroup parameter.  Then, you can use `ThreadGroup#activeCount()` to estimate how many threads are alive in that group.  To wait for the threads to all finish, you could use a while loop that waits until the active thread count of the group is 0, at which point you execute your code.